# iOS swift GKSession usage

Tags: ios, swift

I'd like to use GKSession in one of my swift file. But there is a problem to do so. Here is the error message:

> /Users/Desktop/Snap/Snap/MatchmakingServer.swift:15:1: Type
>   'MatchmakingServer' does not conform to protocol 'NSObjectProtocol'

Here is my code:

```
class MatchmakingServer : GKSessionDelegate {
```

I have no idea what does this mean and how to solve the issue. Can anybody help? Thanks

Comment: I tried this: class MatchmakingServer : NSObject,GKSessionDelegate then there will be no compile error.